# Select table row to perform an action on that row

Tags: php, mysql, sql, html-table

This piece of code produces the table in the image below:

```
<table border='1' cellpadding='5' width='50%' bgcolor='lightyellow'>
    <tr><th>Title of Training Course</th><th>Course Provider</th><th>Venue</th><th>Fee</th></tr>";
    while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        echo "<tr align='center'>
        <td>".$row['tcTitle']."</td>
        <td>".$row['tcProvider']."</td>
        <td>".$row['tcVenue']."</td>
        <td>".$row['tcFee']."</td>";
    }
```

[image]

How do I select a row to perform an action on that selected row? A radio button at the beginning of each row and what?
I want to select a row and click a 'schedule' button at the top of the page to schedule the selected training course.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you are not considering multiple choices you can use regular `a href` html tag to call page containing your informations.

Note that you will have to create `php` page that accepts `GET` requests.

```
    <table border='1' cellpadding='5' width='50%' bgcolor='lightyellow'>
        <tr><th>Title of Training Course</th><th>Course Provider</th><th>Venue</th><th>Fee</th></tr>";
        while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
            echo "<tr align='center'>
            // link the page and make query request with course name or id etc.
            <a href='http://course_info.php?course='".$row['tcTitle']."><td>".$row['tcTitle']."</td></a>
            <td>".$row['tcProvider']."</td>
            <td>".$row['tcVenue']."</td>
            <td>".$row['tcFee']."</td></tr>"; // ! CLOSE THE TAGS </tr>
        }
```